# tensorflow control_flow_ops not working good

Tags: tensorflow

I have a piece of tensorflow code which use `control_flow_ops.cond` to select which result to use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import time

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a_arr = []
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1400, 5600]))
    c_arr = []
    d = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 5600]))
    e_arr = []
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [250])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [250])
    tf.scalar_summary('max/x', tf.reduce_max(x)) 
    for i in range(0, 250):
        a_arr.append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 1400])))
        #c = tf.matmul(a_arr[i], b)
        **c = control_flow_ops.cond(x[i] < y[i], lambda: tf.matmul(a_arr[i], b), lambda:d)**
        e_arr.append(c)
    summary = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    e_arr.append(summary)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('tensor_summary/train',
                                      sess.graph)
    sess.run(init)
    xi = [ 1 for i in range(0, 250) ]
    yi = [ 0 for i in range(0, 250) ]
    print(np.sum(xi < yi))

    for i in range(1000): 
        time_s = time.time() 
        out_arr = sess.run(e_arr, feed_dict={x:xi, y:yi})
        train_writer.add_summary(out_arr[-1], 1)
        time_e = time.time()
        print('duration = %f' %(time_e - time_s))
```

Here `tf.MatMul` should not be executed, but it is actually executed, I run it on tensorflow 0.10.0, and on 32 core CPU, which use more than 900 CPU, and the execution time is 13ms, saving timeline data shows tf.MatMul is also executed. 
 This is a test case to test `tensorflow control_flow_ops.cond`, which is also used in `bidirectional_rnn`.
 How could avoid executing `tf.MatMul` in this case while still make use of `control_flow_ops.cond` to dynamically select one out of the two results? 
 Is there any settings?

Answer (score 0):

The MatMuls are not really executed, even though the timeline includes them. It is a bit confusing and we will consider to remove them. If you time both with and without cond, you should be able to see the difference.

Comment: it is really executed, with cond avg execute time is 0.0135, cpu runs up to 900; without cond avg execute time is 0.0036, cpu usage is only 250. If MatMul is not executed, which operation causes the cpu usage and time difference,  control_flow_ops.cond itself is not a CPU busy operation, the cost should come from MatMuls.

Comment: The time cost with control-flow_ops.cond is actullay much bigger when MatMult is select to exectued, so I think the control_flow_ops.cond is not good enough, even in case that MatMult is not necessary, it executes MatMult occasionally, for parallel execution, because before cond is evaled, the program does not know which branch to select, so it executes both branchs in parallel.

Comment: I ran your code above on my desktop machine. Matmul without cond: avg duration = 0.024408. Matmul with cond: avg duration = 0.009937.

Comment: that's weird, I test on 32 core server,